# why does in android studio preview does not show mobile frame as in most tutorials?

Tags: java

I want to view complete android mobile frame in preview like the screenshots below.

[this is how my preview looks curently its completely white screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mto2j.png)

[this is how i want it to look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rTaUD.png)

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't you just use the Design mode when on your xml file ?[image]

Comment: yeah i used design tab. I just wanted to know that why is mobile frame not visible like in other tutorials. or is this a new feature of updated android studio ?